# How do I dispose of OpenGL resources cleanly on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es2

I am creating a framework for OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android. How can I cleanly dispose of my OpenGL resources when my Android app is done?

I check for `isFinished()` in the `onPause()` event and then dispose of the resources but it calls the OpenGL functions from the main UI thread so it gives me an error (`0x501`).

When I try to call `isFinished()` inside my `onDraw()` in my `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` class, it is never called when I quit my app.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: If you're using GLSurfaceView, you don't really need to do anything -- it does it all for you.  It actually discards everything whenever the activity is paused, which is good to know when figuring out where to allocate stuff, i.e. you want to create all your GL programs in onSurfaceCreated().  See https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/ for an example.

Comment: @fadden: You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been noted, if you are using `GLSurfaceView`, you don't *need* to handle the cleanup as the resources will be released when the context is lost.